# Selectors for automating the Salesforce Mobile Login Screen

Tags: mobile, test-automation

Is there a JS or WDIO library or example anywhere for the best way to automate the Salesforce Mobile APP Logon Page.

My dev team are placing clear identifiers on all the bespoke screens of the app we are developing but I am struggling to get past the initial logon page.

Specifically I am looking for any pre created steps for changing the server to sandbox/scratch org and then logging on.

I have been able to identify the following locators however are there any better ways for finding these same items using appium?

```
const SELECTORS = {
SALESFORCE_SCREEN: 'TBC'
LOGIN_MENU: '~More options',
CHANGE_SERVER: '/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.ListView/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.RelativeLayout/android.widget.TextView',
SANDBOX: '/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.widget.FrameLayout[2]/android.widget.RelativeLayout/android.widget.ScrollView/android.widget.RadioGroup/android.widget.RadioButton[2]',
USERNAME: '/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.widget.FrameLayout[2]/android.widget.RelativeLayout/android.webkit.WebView/android.webkit.WebView/android.view.View/android.view.View[1]/android.view.View[1]/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View/android.view.View[1]/android.view.View[1]/android.view.View[2]/android.widget.EditText',
PASSWORD: '/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.widget.FrameLayout[2]/android.widget.RelativeLayout/android.webkit.WebView/android.webkit.WebView/android.view.View/android.view.View[1]/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.widget.EditText',
LOGIN_TO_APP: '/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.widget.FrameLayout[2]/android.widget.RelativeLayout/android.webkit.WebView/android.webkit.WebView/android.view.View/android.view.View[1]/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.widget.Button'
}
```